# Элементы вылезают за край FlexBox

Tags: css, css3

Почему элементы `input` вылезают за край FlexBox, а не ужимаются по его ширине? Если разместить внутри `div`'ы, то все будет в порядке.

HTML:

```
<div class = "a">
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.a {
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/suxbtzcc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте значение для `input` - `min-width`

```
input {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/suxbtzcc/1/